# Persuade jOOQ not to prefix table names with the database name

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Currently I'm writing a piece of software and when when the customer deploys it to their two environments (QA and Production) their MySQL databases have different names in these environments. For example, in the QA environment the database is called "foo-qa" and Production the database is called "foo-prod". I can't do anything about this, alas.

When I generate the jOOQ classes on our test environment, let's say we have their schema installed on a database called "foo". When jOOQ generates SQL statements, all table references are prefixed by the database name, for example "select from foo.mytable". When we install it to their QA or Prod environments, these statements then do not work, as the database in this environment has a different name.

We connect to the MySQL with a URL like "jdbc:mysql://ip-address/foo-qa" so the DB name is already specified there. We don't need to specify the database name in the statements.

Is there anything I can do to solve this? Ideally to persuade jOOQ to just not prefix the tables with the database name.